# switching language codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am a new coder. I am doing a work where I have to provide the option to the users to select their preferred languages by just clicking on a language they like.
my question is that do I have to make two different controllers(e.g-for two language)
and the similar number of 'two' functions or view files for each language?
or is there any alternative ways to do this?
it is like the site:
http://www.repasdelicieux.com/en/
give me suggestions please.

Answer (score 0):

You can use code igniter [language](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/language.html) class.